# Import custom library from a path using java in robot framework test cases

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I have created a custom library consisting of robot keywords. In order to use these keywords i have to specify

```
Library    abc.xyz.<Class_name>
```

This however does not look clean. I want to just have

```
Library    <class_name>
```

which seems the standard way. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the path till your custom library in PYTHONPATH environment variables
[image: PYTHONPATH]

and then use it like

```
*** Settings ***
Library    abc.java
```

For more options and information you can refer to below answer as well

[Import custom library from a different path in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244476/import-custom-library-from-a-different-path-in-robot-framework)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the library in Robot Framwork consists out of two parts:

```
Library    <Package Path>.<Class_name>
```

In many cases this means something like:

```
Library    org.company.application.<Class_name>
```

This is often reflected in the Java Code as:

```
package org.company.application;

public class SampleKeywordLibrary {
```

In order to only use the class name in Robot Framework it will be necessary to have no Package Path defined in your Class. Depending upon your editor it may require some changes in your project settings as well.

Java:

```
public class SampleKeywordLibrary {

    public static final String ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL";  

    public void MyCustomJavaKeyword() {

    }

}
```

Then the Robot File looks like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   SampleKeywordLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    My Custom Java Keyword
```

When you have exported/compiled it to a Jar file, place it where you want to store it and start Robot Framework from within the Jython context similar to this:

```
C:\Python\jython2.7.0\bin\jython.exe -
 J-Dpython.path=C:\Python\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages 
 -J-cp .;C:\TA\Workspace\StackOverflowJython\SampleKeywordLibrary.jar 
 -m robot.run 
 -s StackOverflowJython.Test 
 C:\TA\Workspace\StackOverflowJython
```