# Python file not getting imported from different directory in robot framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, robotframework

Hi I am trying to import python file in my robot code using library function like this.

```
Library  /Users/test/Desktop/bb/src/json.py
Library  /Users/test/Desktop/bb/src/csv.py
```

I have another python file in same directory that is working. I imported like this.

```
Library  ./API.py
```

But those two files not getting imported. I am using Pycharm and mac os. I tried setting python path changing interpreter. nothing works for me.

Python path in pycharm

```
 ["/Users/test/Desktop/bb/src/"]
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the 'Library' command, but if it follows the same logic as 'import', then the following can help:

Let's say I have a python file 'module_test.py' located in 'C:/Users/Public/'
, and I'm coding in a different directory. Then to import this file, I should add it to the path list before importing:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/Public/')

import module_test

a = module_test.example_function()
```

the argument '0' means it's being added as the first item of the path list.

But I see that this robot framework might not work as straightforward as that. This answer here might help: [Import custom library from a different path in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244476/import-custom-library-from-a-different-path-in-robot-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Well for most of the time your python script fails to import in your robot script is mainly because of 2 reasons-

**1.** **Python Script is having errors.**

**2.** **Specified python file's path under *** settings *** tag is not correct.**

So make sure that python script is executing successfully without any errors and path for python file is correct that you're importing.